# based on the selected value in the Activex combobox how to use vlook up

Tags: excel, vba

based on the selected value in the Activex combobox how to use vlook up in the particular sheet and show that data in the another sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the LinkedCell property and type the address in there. If you want that value in the other spreadsheet you can use a simple worksheet formula `=` to get that done.

Add a script in VBA for the combobox when it changes like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Range("YOURCELL").Value2 = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Then cell "YOURCELL" will contain the value of the combobox whenever its value changes. If you reference that "YOURCELL" cell in your vlookup you are there!

Comment: I think active x controls also have a linked cell property.

Comment: ah you are right, that can be used for this as well, thanks for the comment Pynner I will update the answer

Comment: hi K_B 
i m not sure about the linkedcell property. I m new to macro. can u guide me to do this.i have to take the relevant value from the another column(ie match the value) and consolidate the value in another sheet.Eg. i have a table which consists of three column based on the selected value from combo box i have to take the other two column data and update that in another table in another sheet

Comment: In the development tab click the properties button, there is a property named LinkedCell, there you can type in the cell coordinates (for example A1). Now the ActiveX control is linked to that cell.

Comment: if i link that the data in the combo box the data which i have populated from another sheet is changed.